# How to find the isomorphism between Lie algebra $L_{0}$ and $L_{1}$?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields, vector-space-isomorphism

I think the 2 algebras $L_{0}$ and $L_{1}$ are isomorphic to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(2)$ .

I struggled to find the isomorphism $\phi$ between the Lie algebra $L_{0}$
and $L_{1}$ ?

Let $L_{0}=Span\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}\}$ and $L_{1}=Span\{w_{1},w_{2},w_{3},w_{4}\}$
the Lie algebras.

such that

$ v_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\quad,\quad v_{2}=u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\quad,\quad v_{3}=\sqrt{x}\exp(\frac{b}{2}t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+2b\exp(\frac{b}{2}t)\sqrt{x}u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\quad,\quad v_{4}=\sqrt{x}\exp(-\frac{b}{2}t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
$ w_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\quad,\quad w_{2}=u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\quad,\quad w_{3}=\sqrt{y}\exp(\frac{e}{2}t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+2e\exp(\frac{e}{2}t)\sqrt{y}u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\quad,\quad w_{4}=\sqrt{y}\exp(-\frac{e}{2}t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

with
$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & v_{1} &v_{2} & v_{3}& v_{4} \\ \hline
v_{1} & 0 &0&\frac{b}{2}v_{3}&-\frac{b}{2}v_{4}  \\ \hline
v_{2} &0  &0&0&0 \\ \hline
v_{3} &-\frac{b}{2}v_{3}  &0 &0&-bv_{2} \\ \hline
v_{4} &\frac{b}{2}v_{4}  &0 &bv_{2}&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$   and    $ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & v_{1} &v_{2} & v_{3}& v_{4} \\ \hline
v_{1} & 0 &0&\frac{e}{2}v_{3}&-\frac{e}{2}v_{4}  \\ \hline
v_{2} &0  &0&0&0 \\ \hline
v_{3} &-\frac{e}{2}v_{3}  &0 &0&-ev_{2} \\ \hline
v_{4} &\frac{e}{2}v_{4}  &0 &ev_{2}&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$ are Lie commutators.
Such that $\boxed{b\ne\pm e}$.

Comment: Can't you scale $v_1$ and $v_2$ to map one to the other? I haven't checked but it looks that way.

Comment: i tried the app \psi defined by $\psi :v1-->w1 ,v2-->w2,v3-->w3 and v4-->w4$ but it doesn't verify the condition of isomorphism between Lie algebras means \psi doesn't verify $\psi([v_{i},v_{j}])=[\psi(v_{i}),\psi(v_{j})]$ specially for v_{3} and v_{4} because $b≠+-e$

Comment: If one of $b$ and $e$ is zero then they certainly won't be isomorphic, of course.

Comment: Set $w_3=v_3$, $w_4=v_4$, $w_2=(e/b)v_2$, $w_1=(e/b)v_1$ should work, no?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, indeed. Even more generally, the diagonal matrices below, and these are still not all possible isomorphisms (one can take $f_{1j}$ arbitrary, too).

Comment: yes it works ,thank you so much , it's just i am not familiar with the theory of Lie algebras it's new to me ,can you recommend for me a good course of Lie algebras , youtube video or a book that explain in details ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde i would say $w_{1}=(\frac{b}{e})v1$ instead of what you said $w_{1}=(\frac{e}{b})v1$

Comment: Anas, I didn't say anything about $w_1=(b/e)v_1$. I calculated all possible isomorphisms $f$. By the way, why don't you call $L_0=L(b)$, and $L_1=L(c)$. The symbol $e$ is Euler's number, and is already taken. Also, please accept my answer, if it gives the right result for you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes you're right i'll use those symbols , yes also the isomorphism in not unique , thank you so much for your help i appreciate it , and have a good day ! :)

Comment: @AnasOuknine Whether $w_1=(b/e)v_1$ or $w_1=(e/b)v_1$ depends on which one you are mapping to the other. I think it should be clear from context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the condition that $f\colon L_0\rightarrow L_1$ is a bijective Lie algebra homomorphism by
saying that $f([x,y]_{L_0})=[f(x),f(y)]_{L_1}$ for all $x,y\in L_0$. In operator form this means
$f\circ ad(x)=Ad(f(x))\circ f$ for all $x\in L_0$, so that
$$ 
ad(x)=f^{-1}\circ Ad(f(x))\circ f.
$$
It is enough to consider a basis for $L_0$ for the values of $x$. The characteristic polynomials of $ad(e_i)$ and $Ad(f(e_i))$ must coincide. This gives equations in the variables of $f$. Now a direct computation of all possible $f$ is easy (note that $\det(f)\neq 0$ is a strong condition as well).
For example, we immediately obtain $b=e\cdot f_{11}$ for nonzero $b,e$. So isomorphisms are given, for example, by the diagonal matrices
$$
f=\operatorname{diag}(f_{11},\frac{f_{33}f_{44}}{f_{11}},f_{33},f_{44})
$$
for arbitrary nonzero diagonal elements $f_{33},f_{44}$  from the field, where $f_{11}=\frac{b}{e}$. Note that $e$ is not necessarily $\exp(1)$.